# Is it possible to get a negative value with CSS calc()?

Tags: css, calc

Let's say we have a container that is centered in the viewport ...

```
.centered{margin: 0 auto; width:960px;}
```

... and inside that container I have another that needs to have a width of 100% the viewport width. I could set the margin to ...

```
.widest{margin: 0 -480px}
```

... for example. The thing is that the value won't be -480px, but actually the viewport width (960px) - the .centered width / 2 ... all good and easy with calc(), only I need a result that is a negative value.

```
.widest{
  margin: 0 calc( (100vw - 960px) / 2 );
}
```

I've tried subtracting the lot from 0 to get a negative value, but no go.

I don't want to use JS and I only have issues in Webkit - not with the calc() though - my problem is that if I hack it into submission by doing ...

```
.widest{
  margin: 0 -100%;
}
```

... my page scrolls horisontally in Chrome/Safari.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, to a point. The crucial part is to set the width of the element to `100vw` then offset it by negative half the viewport width plus half the width of the centered element using, e.g. `calc(-50vw + 200px)`:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Lhvzn99L/2/)

Given the HTML

```
<div id='center'>center
    <div id='full'>full width</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
#center {
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#full {
    width:100vw;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    margin-left:calc(-50vw + 200px);
}
```

Comment: That would work if the layout was this simple, and I may just resolve to this, but the container that needs to become a "strap" across the page doesn't have the same height everywhere (although the height is fixed where used) - I'll also have to set margin/padding to the top of the next element to prevent it being overlaid by #full

Comment: ... also: I would really like to know if it's possible to get a negative value from calc()

Comment: I like both approaches, but this one feels a little less hackish ... also feeling a tad daft for not figuring this out by myself. Thanks

Comment: @sw4 this is a nice solution. I cannot, however, figure out how to get it working for responsive `fluid`-ish layout where the `#center` does not have a static width, but a `max-width`, like [here](https://codepen.io/afkatja/full/QMvKGM)

Comment: @afkatja if I've interpreted your point correctly, this article contains the solution required for a fluid center. `.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}` https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Answer (score 103):

A simpler trick than previous ones: `calc(0px - something)` - with an unit - works while `calc(0 - something)` doesn't. See [Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/kg09ufhy/4/)

These "tricks" work:

```
calc(1px - something - 1px);
calc(-1 * something)
calc(0px - something) /* new */
```

where `0 - something` didn't (at least with your example).

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/kg09ufhy/)
[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/kg09ufhy/1/)

Comment: `calc(-1 * something)` is amazing!

Comment: you can also do calc( whatever  / -1 )

Comment: Just want to say thanks, I always forget this for some reason, so when I google it I find this answer and get annoyed that it is so annoyingly simple and wonder why I cannot remember!!

Answer (score 12):

I have another possible solution. You can devide by -2, so you'll get a negative Result

```
.widest{
  margin-left: calc( (100vw - 960px) / -2 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try next solution

```
.some-class {
   margin-left: calc(-1px - ((100vw - 100%) / 2) + 1px);
}
```