# How to become a negative value using calc() with postCSS?

Tags: css, gulp, postcss, calc

```
--space-unit: 1em;
--space-xl: calc(3.25 * var(--space-unit));
```

This `calc(-1 * var(--space-xl));` should be a **negative** value.... but the **-1** is ignored!
The output is 3.25em.

Here is my gulp postcss Setup:

```
.pipe($.postcss([
  $.stylelint(),
  $.autoprefixer(),
  $.cssnano({
    discardComments: {
      removeAll: true
    },
    discardDuplicates: true,
    discardEmpty: true,
    minifyFontValues: true,
    minifySelectors: true
  }),
  $.postcssCustomProperties(), // IE 11
  $.postcssCalc(), // IE 11
  $.postcssReporter({
    clearReportedMessages: true
  })
]))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dont know if this question will shed some light on things for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205039/is-it-possible-to-get-a-negative-value-with-css-calc

Comment: It is `calc(-1 * 3.25 * 1)`. That should be negative but it isn`t. I think postcss causes the error.

Comment: Could you disable the line: $.postcssCalc() and see if it still builds wrong?

Comment: Then the result would be `calc (-1 * calc(3.25 * 1em)) `. Unfortunately that does not help, because the IE11 can not do anything with it. I use postCssCalc to resolve the nested calc and get a final score as the result.